# spring boot application isn't starting in Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, tomcat, jenkins-groovy

I'm cloning the project from git and doing the mvn clean test package sonar:sonar and deploy
but the project doesn't run , I tried the free-style job too but it's the same
it's spring boot JAR application

```
pipeline {
 agent any
 stages{ 
    
         
    
    stage('Git') { 
        steps {
            echo "Cloning" 
            git branch: '*****', url: 'https://github.com/****.git'
    
        }
    }
    
    stage('clean') {
       
       steps{
           echo "Cleaning the project"
           bat 'mvn clean'
       }
    }
    
    stage('Test') {
        
        steps {
            echo "Doing the tests"
            bat 'mvn test'
         
            }
            
        
        }
    stage('SONAR') {
        steps{
             echo "Cleaning Code";
             bat 'mvn sonar:sonar';
       }
    }
    stage('MVN PACKAGE') {
       steps{
           echo "packing the project";
           bat 'mvn package';
       }
       post{
           success {
            archiveArtifacts 'target/*.jar';
           }
       }
    }
    
     stage('NEXUS') {
       steps{
           echo "Deploying the project";
           bat 'mvn  deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=**** -DartifactId=**** -Dversion=1.0 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=deploymentRepo -Durl=http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/ -Dfile=target/****-1.0.jar ';
       }
    }
     
   
  
    } ...}}
```

as the  Tomcat does no start running ,  my Tests aren't running , it's supposed to do 6 tests

```
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  T E S T S
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Results:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  46.816 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-05T02:52:20+01:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

even sonar isn't showing the unit tests in the project,  Can you please help me?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tn.esprit.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>timesheet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>timesheet</name>
    <description>timesheet</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
dependency>

            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

mvn compile

```
D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project>mvn compile 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< tn.esprit.spring:timesheet >---------------------
[INFO] Building timesheet 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ timesheet ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ timesheet ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes
[INFO] /D:/2-SPRING/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/pipeline timesheet project/src/main/java/tn/esprit/spring/TimesheetApplication.java: D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project\src\main\java\tn\esprit\spring\TimesheetApplication.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /D:/2-SPRING/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/pipeline timesheet project/src/main/java/tn/esprit/spring/TimesheetApplication.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  39.156 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-05T04:07:57+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mvn sonar:sonar

```
D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project>mvn sonar:sonar 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< tn.esprit.spring:timesheet >---------------------
[INFO] Building timesheet 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) @ timesheet ---
[INFO] User cache: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.7.7
[INFO] Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Publish mode
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=1186ms
[INFO] Server id: BF41A1F2-AXWFQCU12uRh5xSTg2DK
[INFO] User cache: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=230ms
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=2067ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=1483ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=3900ms
[INFO] Load metrics repository
[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=380ms
[INFO] Project key: tn.esprit.spring:timesheet
[INFO] -------------  Scan timesheet
[INFO] Load server rules
[INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=160ms
[INFO] Base dir: D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project
[INFO] Working dir: D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project\target\sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: fr_FR
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 39 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 8
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=80ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=10ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan
[INFO] 35 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 35/35 source files have been analyzed
[WARNING] Classes not found during the analysis : [javax.annotation.meta.When]
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=4596ms
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan
[INFO] 3 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] 3/3 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=90ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=6680ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java]
[INFO] parsing [D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project\target\surefire-reports]
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=3850ms
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=510ms
[INFO] Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
[INFO] Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=30ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=170ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=130ms
[INFO] 11 files had no CPD blocks
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 24 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 679ms, dir size=187 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 160ms, zip size=107 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 90ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/tn.esprit.spring:timesheet
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXWWYaz_JnFpsXr-KFku
[INFO] Task total time: 57.427 s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:22 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-05T04:09:45+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

deploy

```
D:\2-SPRING\jenkins\jenkins\workspace\pipeline timesheet project>mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=tn.esprit -DartifactId=timesheet -Dversion=1.0 -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=deploymentRepo -Durl=http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/ -Dfile=target/timesheet-1.0.jar  
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< tn.esprit.spring:timesheet>---------------------
[INFO] Building timesheet 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) @ timesheet ---
Uploading to deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/1.0/timesheet-1.0.jar
   
                   
Uploaded to deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/1.0/timesheet-1.0.jar (54 MB at 6.5 MB/s)
Uploading to deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/1.0/timesheet-1.0.pom
Progress (1): 390 B
                   
Uploaded to deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/1.0/timesheet-1.0.pom (390 B at 82 B/s)
Downloading from deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading to deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/maven-metadata.xml
Progress (1): 294 B
                   
Uploaded to deploymentRepo: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/tn/esprit/timesheet/maven-metadata.xml (294 B at 104 B/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.030 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-05T04:10:36+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: Apparently there aren't any tests. (Most likely, this means either that your POM is misconfigured or that your tests aren't in the appropriate location. Show the POM and also the Maven output starting from `test-compile`.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I placed my test class under "src\test\java\tn\esprit\spring"

Comment: `mvn deploy:deploy` _is not the same as_ `mvn deploy`, which runs all of the prior steps. You shouldn't be running `mvn compile` in your pipeline anywhere, you really ought to just run `mvn package` and let it execute `mvn test` along the way, and you haven't shown the output starting from the `test-compile` phase from your Jenkins console.

Comment: However, I have a guess. You see how Spring included JUnit dependencies for you and then you went and added different ones in? Anything in a Boot project where you're providing your own versions is a warning flag that should be double-checked. Most likely you're writing JUnit 4 tests and running under JUnit 5 (and your POM shows explicitly that you have JUnit 5's JUnit 4 test engine disabled).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- thank you for time , actually I just fixed the problem , 
I added  maven-surefire plugin , took oof the junit dependency ( I put it bcz I faced error while deploying to nexus and after changing it the deploying worked) , and to fixe the 401 unauthorized error in mvn deploy:deploy , I just changed mvn version from 3.5.  to 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem , I added maven-surefire plugin , took off the junit dependency ( I put it bcz I faced error while deploying to nexus and after changing it the deploying worked) , and to fix the 401 unauthorized error in mvn deploy:deploy , I just changed mvn version from 3.5. to 3.6.3